# Calculate user overtime

Tags: sql, oracle

I Need help from you. Query to fetch Over-time details done by the employee. Example :- If Users work after 5.00.01 PM the time will be considered as Over-time and Can do over-time till 11.59.59 PM and 5.00.01 PM to 11.59.59 PM can be considered as over-time from Monday to Friday only. For Saturday and Sunday whole day can be considered as Over-time. So I have written query which has some to_char errors. So could you please help to to find further solution. Query :-

```
SELECT user_id,
  start_time,
  end_time,
  CASE
    when to_char(Clock_in_date, 'DY', 'nls_date_language=english') in ('MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI')
      and to_char(end_date_time, 'hh24:mi:ss')> '17:00:00'
    then
      to_char(cast(end_date_time as timestamp) - cast(trunc(end_date_time) + interval '17' hour as timestamp))
    when to_char(Clock_in_date, 'DY', 'nls_date_language=english') in ('SAT', 'SUN')
    then
      to_char((cast(end_date_time as timestamp) - cast(Clock_in_date as timestamp)))
    else
      'no overtime'
    end as overtime
FROM   employee;
```

Final Query Should be like:

[image]

Comment: Try reading through [tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and then edit your question so we can actually help you

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and expected results as formatted text, not images; and to show the errors you are getting. The latest version has `'FRI"'` instead of `'FRI'` but that's just a typo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are some unclear things in your question like how to treat row no. 6 when start date is on saturday and end date is on monday. If someone worked that long (illegal in most countries) isn't it all overtime. If it isn't then what is regular working time (9 to 5 ???).
Anyway, here is one of the ways to do it - a descriptive one. First the sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
          Select 1 "ID",    To_Date('29-AUG-22 15:30:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "START_TIME", To_Date('29-AUG-22 17:30:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "END_TIME" From Dual Union All
          Select 2 "ID",    To_Date('30-AUG-22 15:30:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "START_TIME", To_Date('30-AUG-22 20:30:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "END_TIME" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 "ID",    To_Date('31-AUG-22 15:30:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "START_TIME", To_Date('31-AUG-22 17:00:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "END_TIME" From Dual Union All
          Select 4 "ID",    To_Date('01-SEP-22 17:45:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "START_TIME", To_Date('01-SEP-22 23:45:10', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "END_TIME" From Dual Union All
          Select 5 "ID",    To_Date('02-SEP-22 15:45:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "START_TIME", To_Date('02-SEP-22 23:59:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "END_TIME" From Dual Union All
          Select 6 "ID",    To_Date('27-AUG-22 10:30:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "START_TIME", To_Date('29-AUG-22 17:30:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "END_TIME" From Dual Union All
          Select 7 "ID",    To_Date('28-AUG-22 11:30:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "START_TIME", To_Date('28-AUG-22 20:30:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "END_TIME" From Dual 
        ),
```

... to show the data in a different way there is another CTE named grid...

```sql
    grid AS
        (
            Select
                ID "ID",
                To_Char(START_TIME, 'dd-MON-yy') "START_DATE",
                To_Char(START_TIME, 'DY') "START_DAY",
                To_Char(START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') "START_TIME",
                CASE WHEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'DY') IN('SAT', 'SUN') THEN 'Weekend' ELSE 'Workday' END "START_TYPE",
                --
                To_Char(END_TIME, 'dd-MON-yy') "END_DATE",
                To_Char(END_TIME, 'DY') "END_DAY",
                To_Char(END_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') "END_TIME",
                CASE WHEN To_Char(END_TIME, 'DY') IN('SAT', 'SUN') THEN 'Weekend' ELSE 'Workday' END "END_TYPE",
                --
                CASE 
                    WHEN TRUNC(START_TIME, 'dd') = TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd') THEN
                        CASE 
                            WHEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'DY') IN('SAT', 'SUN') THEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' - ' || To_Char(END_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss')
                        ELSE
                           CASE 
                              WHEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') > '17:00:00' And To_Char(END_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') > To_Char(START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') THEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' - ' || To_Char(END_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss')  
                              WHEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') <= '17:00:00' And To_Char(END_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') >= '17:00:00' THEN '17:00:00 - ' || To_Char(END_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss')
                           END
                        END
                ELSE
                    CASE 
                        WHEN TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd') - TRUNC(START_TIME, 'dd') = 1 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'DY') IN('SAT', 'SUN') THEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' - ' ELSE '17:00:00 - ' END || REPLACE(To_Char(TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd') - 1, 'hh24:mi:ss'), '00:00:00', '23:59:59')
                        WHEN TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd') - TRUNC(START_TIME, 'dd') = 2 THEN
                            CASE WHEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'DY') IN('SAT', 'SUN') THEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' - ' ELSE '17:00:00 - ' END || REPLACE(To_Char(TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd') - 2, 'hh24:mi:ss'), '00:00:00', '23:59:59')
                    ELSE
                        To_Char(START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' - ' || To_Char(END_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss')
                    END
                END "OVERTIME_SPAN_0",
                CASE 
                    WHEN TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd') - TRUNC(START_TIME, 'dd') = 1 THEN 
                        CASE WHEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'DY') IN('SAT', 'SUN') THEN To_Char(TRUNC(START_TIME, 'dd') + 1, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' - ' ELSE '17:00:00 - ' END || REPLACE(To_Char(END_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss'), '00:00:00', '23:59:59')
                    WHEN TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd') - TRUNC(START_TIME, 'dd') = 2 THEN
                        CASE WHEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'DY') IN('SAT', 'SUN') THEN To_Char(TRUNC(START_TIME, 'dd') + 1, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' - ' ELSE '17:00:00 - ' END || REPLACE(To_Char(TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd') - 1, 'hh24:mi:ss'), '00:00:00', '23:59:59')
                ELSE
                    Null
                END  "OVERTIME_SPAN_1",
                CASE 
                    WHEN TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd') - TRUNC(START_TIME, 'dd') = 2 THEN
                        CASE WHEN To_Char(START_TIME, 'DY') IN('SAT', 'SUN') THEN To_Char(TRUNC(START_TIME, 'dd') + 2, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' - ' ELSE '17:00:00 - ' END || To_Char(END_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss')
                ELSE
                    Null
                END  "OVERTIME_SPAN_2"
            From
                tbl
        )
```

... the grid resulting dataset looks like this:

```sql
/*
   ID START_DATE START_DAY START_TIME START_TYPE END_DATE  END_DAY END_TIME END_TYPE OVERTIME_SPAN_0       OVERTIME_SPAN_1         OVERTIME_SPAN_2   
----- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- --------- ------- -------- -------- --------------------- ----------------------- -------------------
    1 29-AUG-22  MON       15:30:00   Workday    29-AUG-22 MON     17:30:00 Workday  17:00:00 - 17:30:00                                               
    2 30-AUG-22  TUE       15:30:00   Workday    30-AUG-22 TUE     20:30:00 Workday  17:00:00 - 20:30:00                                               
    3 31-AUG-22  WED       15:30:00   Workday    31-AUG-22 WED     17:00:00 Workday  17:00:00 - 17:00:00                                               
    4 01-SEP-22  THU       17:45:00   Workday    01-SEP-22 THU     23:45:10 Workday  17:45:00 - 23:45:10                                               
    5 02-SEP-22  FRI       15:45:00   Workday    02-SEP-22 FRI     23:59:00 Workday  17:00:00 - 23:59:00                                               
    6 27-AUG-22  SAT       10:30:00   Weekend    29-AUG-22 MON     17:30:00 Workday  10:30:00 - 23:59:59    00:00:00 - 23:59:59    00:00:00 - 17:30:00 
    7 28-AUG-22  SUN       11:30:00   Weekend    28-AUG-22 SUN     20:30:00 Weekend  11:30:00 - 20:30:00                                               
*/
```

There are some data derived from sample data to test and show you the ways to split the data in a way that is suitable to folow the logic from your question.
...now we have all time spans that we need to calculate the overtimes. Here is the main query:

```sql
SELECT
    grid.ID "ID",
    START_DATE,
    START_TIME,
    END_DATE,
    END_TIME,
    OVERTIME_SPAN_0,
    CASE 
        WHEN OVERTIME_SPAN_0 Is Null THEN 0 
    ELSE 
        (   (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_0, 12, 2)) * 3600) + (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_0, 15, 2)) * 60) + To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_0, 18, 2))  ) - 
        (   (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_0, 1, 2)) * 3600) + (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_0, 4, 2)) * 60) + To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_0, 7, 2))  )
    END "OVERTIME_0",
    OVERTIME_SPAN_1,
    CASE 
        WHEN OVERTIME_SPAN_1 Is Null THEN 0 
    ELSE 
        (   (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_1, 12, 2)) * 3600) + (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_1, 15, 2)) * 60) + To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_1, 18, 2))  ) - 
        (   (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_1, 1, 2)) * 3600) + (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_1, 4, 2)) * 60) + To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_1, 7, 2))  )
    END "OVERTIME_1",
    OVERTIME_SPAN_2, 
    CASE 
        WHEN OVERTIME_SPAN_1 Is Null THEN 0 
    ELSE 
        (   (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_2, 12, 2)) * 3600) + (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_2, 15, 2)) * 60) + To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_2, 18, 2))  ) - 
        (   (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_2, 1, 2)) * 3600) + (To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_2, 4, 2)) * 60) + To_Number(SubStr(OVERTIME_SPAN_2, 7, 2))  )
    END "OVERTIME_2"
FROM
    grid
/*  R e s u l t :
    ID START_DATE START_TIME END_DATE  END_TIME OVERTIME_SPAN_0      OVERTIME_0 OVERTIME_SPAN_1       OVERTIME_1 OVERTIME_SPAN_2     OVERTIME_2
------ ---------- ---------- --------- -------- -------------------- ---------- --------------------- ---------- ------------------- ----------
     1 29-AUG-22  15:30:00   29-AUG-22 17:30:00 17:00:00 - 17:30:00        1800                                0                              0 
     2 30-AUG-22  15:30:00   30-AUG-22 20:30:00 17:00:00 - 20:30:00       12600                                0                              0 
     3 31-AUG-22  15:30:00   31-AUG-22 17:00:00 17:00:00 - 17:00:00           0                                0                              0 
     4 01-SEP-22  17:45:00   01-SEP-22 23:45:10 17:45:00 - 23:45:10       21610                                0                              0 
     5 02-SEP-22  15:45:00   02-SEP-22 23:59:00 17:00:00 - 23:59:00       25140                                0                              0 
     6 27-AUG-22  10:30:00   29-AUG-22 17:30:00 10:30:00 - 23:59:59       48599 00:00:00 - 23:59:59        86399 00:00:00 - 17:30:00      63000 
     7 28-AUG-22  11:30:00   28-AUG-22 20:30:00 11:30:00 - 20:30:00       32400                                0                              0
*/
```

... and the resulting dataset containes overtimes (in seconds) calculated from the sample data. As said, there are still some questions regarding the overtime, but I hope this could be helpfull to you to get your own way to deal with it.
Regards...